# How to set the height of QWebView to just hold its contents?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

*HtmlEditor* is meant to be empty, editable and display only one line at first. Its height is just enough to hold one line, no more bigger or smaller. The height of it will extend as the user inputs more lines of text.

But the problem is, the height of *HtmlEditor* is a little smaller at first. I guess it is because the height is set to be exactly the size of the font, but there are also margins around the font too, which isn't considered. After inputting a character in it, the height of *HtmlEditor* will soon get bigger, just enough to hold the text thanks to the `sizeChange` function. I wish I could set the MaximumHeight of *HtmlEditor* as `self.page().mainFrame().contentsSize().height()` at first too, because `contentsSize().height()` seems perfect to hold the text. But it seems impossible considering there is no contents at all at first, in which case `contentsSize().height()` is just a wrong number. How to do the trick, setting both MaximumHeight and MinimumHeight of *HtmlEditor* as the height of the contents to just hold it?

```
class HtmlEditor(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.page().setContentEditable(True)
        self.page().contentsChanged.connect(self.sizeChange)
        self.setUpFont(10)

    def setUpFont(self, fontSize):
        self.htmlEditorSettings = self.settings()
        self.htmlEditorSettings.setFontSize(QWebSettings.DefaultFontSize, fontSize)
        self.setMaximumHeight(fontSize)

    def sizeChange(self):
        docHeight = self.page().mainFrame().contentsSize().height()
        self.setMinimumHeight(docHeight)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hackish solution using [QFontMetrics](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html). I'm considering it hackish since I had to implement the text leading manually. There's probably a good reason why `QFontMetrics` seems to be spitting out a bad value, but this should work for you in the mean time.

We take all of the sizing information for a line of text, figure out how many lines we're working with, and adjust the size of `QWebView` accordingly:

```
class HtmlEditor(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.page().setContentEditable(True)
        self.page().contentsChanged.connect(self.update_height)
        self.settings().setFontSize(QWebSettings.DefaultFontSize, 10)
        self.setContentsMargins(QMargins(10, 10, 10, 10))
        self.update_height()

    def update_height(self):
        num_lines = len(self.page().mainFrame().toPlainText().splitlines())
        if num_lines == 0:
            num_lines = 1
        margins = self.contentsMargins()
        metrics = self.fontMetrics()
        leading = 4  # You should be able to do metrics.leading() but it was giving me 0 for some reason
        line_height = metrics.height()  # For the above reason, we use height() here instead of metrics.lineSpacing() and add the leading manually
        self.setFixedHeight((line_height * num_lines) + (leading * (num_lines - 1)) + margins.top() + margins.bottom())
```

I would be greatly appreciative if somebody could chime in here with a reasoning for the strange behavior of `QFontMetrics` in this scenario.

Comment: That is weird. I just tried your code. Not matter what `QWebSettings.DefaultFontSize` is, `metrics.height()` is always a fixed value: 26, so the height of `HtmlEditor` is inaccurate.

Comment: I tried to set the height of `HtmlEditor` as `fontsize + margins.top() + margins.bottom()`, and it worked. Thank you for you inspiration!

Comment: Glad you were able to find a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank @MichaelBlakeley, this is my final code:

```
class HtmlEditor(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.page().setContentEditable(True)
        self.page().contentsChanged.connect(self.sizeChange)
        self.setupFont(10)

    def setupFont(self, fontSize):
        self.htmlEditorSettings = self.settings()
        self.htmlEditorSettings.setFontSize(QWebSettings.DefaultFontSize, fontSize)
        margins = self.contentsMargins()
        self.setFixedHeight(fontsize + margins.top() + margins.bottom())

    def sizeChange(self):
        docHeight = self.page().mainFrame().contentsSize().height()
        self.setFixedHeight(docHeight)
```